# remove _links object from wp rest api response by filter or hook

Tags: wordpress-rest-api

I have removed unwanted data by `unset($data->data['field_name'])`  from json output. For this I am using wordpress filter `rest_prepare_`.

But how we remove _links object from JSON output?

Answer (score 5):

I don’t know how to ***unset***, but you can set which variables to return.

```
function prepare_rest($data, $post, $request){
    return [
        'id'    => $data->data['id'],
        'title' => $data->data['title']['rendered']
    ];
}

add_filter('rest_prepare_post', 'prepare_rest', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this way not allow adding protected items, like _embedded.

Answer (score 5):

Gotta be careful removing stuff from the API, but if you're sure you want to remove this, it can be done like this:

```
function so_45027789_rest_prepare_post($data, $post, $request)
{
    foreach($data->get_links() as $_linkKey => $_linkVal) {
        $data->remove_link($_linkKey);
    }
    return $data;
}

add_filter('rest_prepare_post', 'so_45027789_rest_prepare_post', 1, 3);
```

I'd recommend only doing so if you're explicitly asking for a smaller response in your implementation with the API, thereby leaving default usage of the API untouched, like via a query variable:

```
function so_45027789_rest_prepare_post($data, $post, $request)
{
    $params = $request->get_params();
    if(isset($params['_minimal'])) {
        foreach($data->get_links() as $_linkKey => $_linkVal) {
            $data->remove_link($_linkKey);
        }
    }
    return $data;
}

add_filter('rest_prepare_post', 'so_45027789_rest_prepare_post', 1, 3);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not very good solution but work.

```
function contract_remove_links( $data, $post, $context ) {

    $data->remove_link( 'collection' );
    $data->remove_link( 'self' );
    $data->remove_link( 'about' );
    $data->remove_link( 'author' );
    $data->remove_link( 'replies' );
    $data->remove_link( 'version-history' );
    $data->remove_link( 'https://api.w.org/featuredmedia' );
    $data->remove_link( 'https://api.w.org/attachment' );
    $data->remove_link( 'https://api.w.org/term' );
    $data->remove_link( 'curies' );

    return $data;
}

add_filter( 'rest_prepare_post', 'contract_remove_links', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rest_prepare_post` is the right filter to use, but the `_links` field is dynamically generated by WordPress. So you can’t remove things to it directly.

you can add your own `link` in this parameter or you can remove the default link from the "_links".

Here is the code....

```
add_filter( 'rest_prepare_post', function ( $response ) {
$response->add_link( 'yourrel', rest_url( 'yourendpoint/thing' ), array(
    'embeddable' => true,
) );

$response->remove_link( 'collection' );

return $response;
} );
```

Comment: How do you specify to replace the link in `routes` ->`_links` -> `self` -> `href` as well as the root `url` and `home`  with another link?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you cannot remove it, it’s protected.

```
    unset( $data->links );

    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot access protected property WP_REST_Response::$links 

    /wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php(311)
        Line 1567:  $response->add_links( $this->prepare_links( $post ) );
        Line 1608:  protected function prepare_links( $post ) {
```